# for delims comparing files

Tags: batch-file, file-compare

I'm totally not a programmer, but I'll need a .bat-script to do some stuff. One of them is comparing files..
I'll have 2 directories that have multiple zip-files, and need to compare them (with an easy fc-command).

```
C:\ |__DIR 1
|   |_ a.zip
|   |_ b.zip
|   |_ c.zip
|   |_...
| 
|__DIR 2
    |_ a.zip
    |_ b.zip
    |_ c.zip
    |_...
```

I'll try to get the files in a variable, but it always fails...
When using:

```
SET "dir_A=C:\DIR 1"
SET "dir_B=C:\DIR 2"

for %%a in ("%dir_A%\*.zip") do ( echo %%a )
```

**Output:**

```
C:\DIR 1\a.zip
C:\DIR 1\b.zip
C:\DIR 1\c.zip
```

When using:

```
for /f "delims" %%a in ('dir /b %dir_A%\^*.zip') do ( echo %%a )
```

**Output:**

```
a.zip
b.zip
c.zip
```

and when I'm using:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b %dir_A%\^*.zip') do ( 
    set "filename=%%a"
    echo %filename%
)
```

I'll get:
**Output**

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

Is there a way to get the files in an variable to so i can use it?
I wanna use it in a bat file like:
for *.zip file => filename...

```
fc %dir_A%\%filename% %dir_B%\%file > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto error
else...
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable expansions in CMD batch files are processed differently compared to other languages – not as part of command execution but as part of parsing the input (i.e. very early stage, much like C preprocessor macros).

So the `%filename%` is expanded just once when the `for` lines are read (the entire `(...)` group is read as a single unit) – at which point it expands to a single string – and although the variable does change every iteration, the `echo` command is not re-expanded.

There are a few workarounds you can use:

- Write PowerShell instead. It has its own quirks (and sometimes you still have to call out to Cmd with `cmd /c`), but overall it's much closer to standard languages in behavior.

  ```
  $dirA = "C:\foo"
  get-childitem -recurse "$dirA\*.zip" | foreach-object {
      $file = $_
      $filename = $_.Name
      echo "Got '$filename' which was last touched $($file.LastWriteTime)"
  }
  ```
- Write Python instead.

  ```python
  from pathlib import Path
  dirA = Path("C:/foo")

  for item in dirA.glob("*.zip"):
      print(f"Got {item.name} (at {item})")
  ```
- Instead of using a `(...)` group, move the operations under their own `:label` which you can then `call` like a subroutine. (Don't forget to have it jump to :EOF at the end.)

  ```
  @echo off & setlocal

  for [...] do call :HandleFile "%%~a"
  goto :EOF

  :HandleFile
      set fullpath=%1
      set filename=%~nx1
      echo Got %filename% (full path %fullpath%)
      goto :EOF
  ```
- Enable "delayed expansion", which activates a *second* kind of expansion using `!variable!` that happens later in the process. (And sometimes incurs its own headaches, as it gets applied even to the results of %-expansions!)

  ```
  @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  for [...] do (
      set fullpath=%%a
      set filename=%%~nxa
      echo Got !filename! (full path !fullpath!).
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You don't need to use this escape **`^`** in **`^*.zip`**, remove it.

```bat
for /f "delims" %%a in ('dir /b %dir_A%\  ^  *.zip') do echo %%a

for /f "delims" %%a in ('dir /b %dir_A%\*.zip') do echo %%a
```

---

**2.** You are working with a folder (`DirSpace1`) that has space in their name, so use double quotes `""`.

```bat
for /f "delims" %%a in ('dir /b %dir_A%\*.zip') do echo %%a

for /f "delims" %%a in ('dir /b "%dir_A%\*.zip"') do echo %%a
```

---

**3.** The correct way to remove delimiters uses **`=`** => `"delims="` or `delims^= %%...`:

```bat
for /f "delims?" %%a in ('dir /b %dir_A%\*.zip') do echo %%a

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%dir_A%\*.zip"') do echo %%a

:: or.. 

for /f delims^= %%a in ('dir /b "%dir_A%\*.zip"') do echo %%a
```

---

**4.** You are saving a file value in a variable and always replacing it with a new name in a loop, it would be useful to suggest that you assume a name that can be incremented in name to assign a value in a loop working file by file, but this complicates things a bit:

```bash
@echo off && setlocal

set "_dir_A=C:\DIR 1"
set "_dir_B=C:\DIR 2"

set /a "_cnt=0, _ledz=1000"

for /f delims^= %%G in =;(' @where.exe "%_Dir_A%:*.zip" ');= do =;(
     2>nul where.exe "%_Dir_B%:%%~nxG" 1>nul && =;(
     @call set^ /a "_num=%%_ledz%%+%%_cnt%%"
     @call set^ "_A_%%_num:~-3%%=%%~nxG"
     @call set^ /a "_cnt+=1"
    );= || call %:^O "%%~G"
    );=

call set^ /a "_cnt-=1"
for /l %%L in =;( 0, 1,%_cnt%);= do call set^ /a "_x=%%_ledz%%+%%~L" && =;(
     "%ComSpec%" /v:on /q /s /c "echo/File !_x:~-3!: "!_A_%%_x:~-3%%!"" );=

%:^O 
if "%~nx1" == "" endlocal && goto =:eof
echo/ERROR: "%%_Dir_B%%\%~nx1" & exit /b
```

---

**Additional Resources:**

- [`cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`if /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`Where /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)
- [Redirection in Batch Files](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - [`|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)
- [`cmd /?` | (Refer: `%conSpec%`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)
- [Parameter Extensions (Refer: `%%~ni`, `%~nxi`)](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)